# async parallel node js issue

Tags: node.js, express, asynchronous

I am trying to run two tasks parallely using the async module in node js.
When I run the code, I get this error:

string is not a function

```
TypeError: string is not a function
    at /Users/Username/expressStarter/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:718:13
    at async.forEachOf.async.eachOf
```

My code:

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  async.parallel([getIOSData(),
    getAndroidData()], function(){
    console.log('done');
  })
   res.render('index',{title: "Reviews"});
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work :

```
async.parallel([getIOSData,
    getAndroidData], function(){
    console.log('done');
})
```

Edit : You have to render your page in the callback function, not outside (asynchronous) :

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  async.parallel([getIOSData(),
    getAndroidData()], function(){
    console.log('done');
    res.render('index',{title: "Reviews"});
  })
});
```

Comment: Actually this didnt work the way I expected.  My code is: router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  async.parallel([getIOSData,
      getAndroidData], function(){
      console.log('done');
  });
   res.render('index',{title: "Reviews"});
}); Right now I have to hit the localhost:3000 refresh twice for both the functions to be called. I want to call it in one go.

Comment: If I put the render in the call back, it doesnt seem to work. I notice that the data is pushed into mongo (so getIOS() and getAndroidData() are working fine, )but in the front end, it waits indefinitely. Nothing gets populated in the front end.